# HSRP issue both device active stats

Tags: cisco, switch, router, hsrp, fhrp

Here is the Diagram. 
[image]

Ip address:

ISP:

```
[VIP]- 10.107.25.5
[R1] - 10.107.25.6
[R2] - 10.107.25.7
```

Me:

```
[VIP] - 10.107.25.10
[SW1] - 10.107.25.11
[SW2] - 10.107.25.12
```

Configuration on port:

```
SW1


    interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
    description #Primary Link WTBB 1#
    no switchport
    ip address 10.107.25.11 255.255.255.248
    standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
    standby 30 priority 110
    standby 30 preempt

SW2


    interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
    description # Secondary Link WTBB 2#
    no switchport
    ip address 10.107.25.12 255.255.255.248
    standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
    no standby 30 preempt
```

Notes: Interesting thing i can't ping from `10.107.25.11` to `10.107.25.12` I am not sure what is other side of ISP, As per document .11 should ping .12 so they can say hello to each other using `L2` layer right?

This is what i did but i think its wrong way to configure HSRP

[SW1]

```
interface vlan3
ip address 10.107.25.11 255.255.255.248
standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
standby 30 priority 110
standby 30 preempt 

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
switchport access allow vlan 3
```

[SW2]

```
interface vlan3
ip address 10.107.25.12 255.255.255.248
standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
standby 30 priority 110
standby 30 preempt 

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
switchport access allow vlan 3
```

On Trunk interface i allowed `Vlan3`

Now i can ping from .11 to .12 ip address using vlan3 (L2) network. and HSRP is happy (active/standby).

But if i unplug cable on port `G1/0/1` trying to mimic cable is cut and my VIP will failover. but problem is .11 and .12 is on `vlan3` interface and they are `UP` no matter you cut the cable or not..

How do i solve this issue in above scenario?

Comment: What are the switch models, and how are they connected together?

Comment: Are they in a stack?

Comment: No they are not stack... it is independent

Comment: Then why is the interface on the first switch `G2/0/1`? The first number, `2`, is the switch position in a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to reflect new information in the question:**

Based on your multiple edits which *finally* give the whole picture (I hope), you can try something like this, but using the switch stacking capability in the alternative configuration will give you a better solution.

Your connection to the ISP will need to be on the same subnet as the ISP.

SW1:

```
track 3 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1 line-protocol
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description #Primary Link WTBB 1#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description #Link to switch 2#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 10.107.25.11 255.255.255.240
 standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
 standby 30 priority 105
 standby 30 preempt
 standby 30 track 3 decrement 10
 no shutdown
!
```

SW2:

```
track 3 interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1 line-protocol
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description #Primary Link WTBB 2#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description #Link to switch 1#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 10.107.25.12 255.255.255.240
 standby 30 ip 10.107.25.10
 standby 30 priority 100
 standby 30 preempt
 standby 30 track 3 decrement 10
 no shutdown
!
```

This allows the ISP HSRP to work since the ISP routers need to be able to talk to each other on the same VLAN so that the ISP HSRP works.

**Alternate (stacked) Configuration:**

SW1/2 stack:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description #Primary Link WTBB 1#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
 description #Primary Link WTBB 2#
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 no shutdown
!
interface Vlan3
 ip address 10.107.25.10 255.255.255.240
 no shutdown
!
```

This configuration gives you all the benefits of the two separate switches but solves your problem of having two separate switches with separate IP addresses. The stack is configured as a single switch and is managed as a single device. Besides the data sharing, the 3850s can also do power sharing so that if one of them loses power, the other can keep both switches running. You will also save precious public IP addresses.

Comment: If i won't do `HSRP` then how ISP will sending traffic toward my SW? he need to put gateway in his routing table right?

Comment: @Satish What are your subnet assignments from the ISP?

Comment: you said in link failure HSRP will failover automatically, true but on ISP router they have to provide Revers route to my subnet behind the SW1 and SW2, My subnet is `71.200.10.X/24`, if SW1 fiber cut then what will happen explain me?

Comment: You are doling out the information bit-by-bit. How can you expect us to help you without the whole story? You didn't say anything about another subnet behind the subnet which we were discussing. I was working with the knowledge of a single subnet, but adding this other one changes things.

Comment: I am sorry, i thought answer of this question will be easy so i didn't put any other info, but look like i was wrong. We have two link 1. Primary and 2. Standby or whatever you call so in case cable cut we won't be off the hook. How do i create network which can provide me failover in cable cut scenario or switch failed scenario

Comment: Look at my edited answer. The real solution would be to stack the switches. This simplifies things a lot without sacrificing the benefits of two physical switches.

Comment: `track` sounds good.. let me give it a shot with that configuration and i will get back to you

Comment: I have run your configuration on my `GNS3`, it works if i shutdown `GigabitEthernet1/0/1`  but it doesn't work if i shutdown remove `[R1]` interface. I am just trying to simulate `fiber cut` scenario. On Ethernet interface line protocole is alway up right??

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be a problem that line protocol stays up. The ISP HSRP will fail over since the HSRP messages can't go to the other router, so you won't have a problem.

Comment: @Satish, Why are you bothering with all this? It would be much simpler to just stack the two switches. There really is no downside, and you gain some benefits like easier configuration and faster failover.

Comment: ++++++1 vote for you... its working but i wanted to check all side.. like fiber cut, interface down, switch is dead etc..  We can't do stack because we don't have stack cable and we have running customer on it.. so i can't touch that switch

Comment: I wish if my ethernet line protocol down if i pull ethernet cable. is that possible?

Comment: The 3850 switches each come with a stack cable. There is no need to worry about the line protocol. When the link is broken, the ISP's HSRP message can't go between the ISP routers, so the Active will fail over. It doesn't matter on your side since you are connected on a VLAN, and the remaining ISP router can still get to both switches through the remaining link.

Comment: You need to remember that these are not routed links, you are using a VLAN. HSRP won't work with routed links since they would be on different subnets.