# Cisco Route Tagging Question

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, packet-tracer

We have created a network as shown in the topology:

[image]

The goal is for subnets/networks in LAN_SW to tagged and the tagged networks to be recognized by routers, CPE, PE CORE_P, REMOTE_PE, REMOTE_CPE and finally placed in the routing table of REMOTE_LAN_SW.

I have tagged ip prefix-list 7.7.7.7/32 with tag 100 in LAND_SW. However, as you will see in show commands, the tag isn't being picked by eigrp.

Can you please take a look at the configuration and show commands and let me know where I might be going wrong?

**CORE_P:**

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 description TO PE
 ip address 10.0.0.4 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description TO RR
 ip address 10.2.0.4 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 description TO REMOTE PE
 ip address 10.1.0.4 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
!
router ospf 1
!
router ospf 100
 network 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
!
CORE_P#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/11] via 10.0.0.3, 1d22h, Ethernet0/0
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.4 [110/11] via 10.2.0.9, 1d22h, Ethernet0/2
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.5 [110/11] via 10.1.0.5, 1d22h, Ethernet1/1
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 6 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.0.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       10.0.0.4/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
C       10.1.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet1/1
L       10.1.0.4/32 is directly connected, Ethernet1/1
C       10.2.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
L       10.2.0.4/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
CORE_P#show ip eigrp topology
```

**CPE:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description connected to lan_sw
 ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description connected to PE
 ip address 100.65.0.2 255.255.255.252
!
router eigrp 100
 network 192.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
 redistribute bgp 65000 metric 100000 100 255 1 1500 route-map BGP_TO_EIGRP
 eigrp router-id 2.2.2.2
!
router bgp 65000
 bgp router-id 2.2.2.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 100.65.0.1 remote-as 3549
!
 address-family ipv4
  network 2.2.2.2 mask 255.255.255.255
  redistribute eigrp 100 route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP
  neighbor 100.65.0.1 activate
  neighbor 100.65.0.1 send-community both
  neighbor 100.65.0.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  exit-address-family
!
route-map BGP_TO_EIGRP permit 5
 set tag 10
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP deny 5
 match tag 10
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP permit 10
 match tag 100
 set community 65000:100 65000:999
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP permit 20
 match tag 200
 set community 65000:200
!
CPE#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    1.1.1.1 [170/2585600] via 192.168.0.1, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       2.2.2.2 is directly connected, Loopback0
     6.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       6.6.6.6 [20/0] via 100.65.0.1, 1d19h
     9.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    9.9.9.9 [170/2585600] via 192.168.0.1, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    10.0.40.0 [170/2585600] via 192.168.0.1, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
     50.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       50.50.50.50 [20/0] via 100.65.0.1, 1d19h
     100.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       100.65.0.0/30 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
L       100.65.0.2/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
B       100.100.100.100/32 [20/0] via 100.65.0.1, 1d19h
     192.168.0.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       192.168.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       192.168.0.2/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
CPE#show ip eigrp topology
EIGRP-IPv4 Topology Table for AS(100)/ID(2.2.2.2)
Codes: P - Passive, A - Active, U - Update, Q - Query, R - Reply,
       r - reply Status, s - sia Status
P 50.50.50.50/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 100.100.100.100/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 192.168.0.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 281600
        via Connected, Ethernet0/0
P 10.0.40.0/30, 1 successors, FD is 2585600, tag is 100
       via 192.168.0.1 (2585600/2560000), Ethernet0/0
P 2.2.2.2/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
       via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 6.6.6.6/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
       via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 1.1.1.1/32, 1 successors, FD is 2585600, tag is 100
       via 192.168.0.1 (2585600/2560000), Ethernet0/0
P 9.9.9.9/32, 1 successors, FD is 2585600, tag is 100
       via 192.168.0.1 (2585600/2560000), Ethernet0/0
```

**LAN_SW:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback999
 ip address 9.9.9.9 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description connected to CPE
 no switchport
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description connected to REMOTE_LAN_SW
 no switchport
 ip address 10.0.40.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
!
router eigrp 100
 network 10.9.1.32 0.0.0.31
 network 192.168.0.0
 redistribute connected metric 1000 0 255 1 1500 route-map TAG
 redistribute bgp 500 metric 1000 0 255 1 1500 route-map BGP-TO-EIGRP
!
router bgp 500
 bgp router-id 9.9.9.9
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.0.40.2 remote-as 600
!
 address-family ipv4
  redistribute connected
  redistribute eigrp 100 route-map EIGRP-TO-BGP
  neighbor 10.0.40.2 activate
  neighbor 10.0.40.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  exit-address-family
!
ip prefix-list TAG seq 5 permit 7.7.7.7/32
!
route-map EIGRP-TO-BGP permit 10
!
route-map BGP-TO-EIGRP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list TAG
 set tag 555
!
route-map TAG permit 10
 set tag 100
!
LAN_SW#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       1.1.1.1 is directly connected, Loopback0
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    2.2.2.2 [170/307200] via 192.168.0.2, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
     6.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       6.6.6.6 [20/307200] via 10.0.40.2, 1d19h
     9.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       9.9.9.9 is directly connected, Loopback999
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
C       10.0.40.0/30 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
L       10.0.40.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
B       10.9.1.0/27 [20/0] via 10.0.40.2, 1d19h
     50.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       50.50.50.50 [20/0] via 10.0.40.2, 1d19h
     100.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       100.100.100.100 [20/307200] via 10.0.40.2, 1d19h
     192.168.0.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       192.168.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       192.168.0.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
LAN_SW#show ip eigrp topology
EIGRP-IPv4 Topology Table for AS(100)/ID(9.9.9.9)
Codes: P - Passive, A - Active, U - Update, Q - Query, R - Reply,
       r - reply Status, s - sia Status
P 50.50.50.50/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 192.168.0.2 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 100.100.100.100/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 192.168.0.2 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 192.168.0.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 281600
        via Connected, Ethernet0/0
P 10.0.40.0/30, 1 successors, FD is 281600, tag is 100
        via Rconnected (2560000/0)
P 2.2.2.2/32, 1 successors, FD is 307200, tag is 10
        via 192.168.0.2 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 6.6.6.6/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 192.168.0.2 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 1.1.1.1/32, 1 successors, FD is 128256, tag is 100
        via Rconnected (2560000/0)
P 9.9.9.9/32, 1 successors, FD is 128256, tag is 100
        via Rconnected (2560000/0)
```

**PE:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 100 area 0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description connected to core_p
 ip address 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description connected to cpe
 ip vrf forwarding JM_CORP
 ip address 100.65.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
router ospf 100
 network 3.3.3.3 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
!
router bgp 3549
 bgp router-id 3.3.3.3
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 remote-as 3549
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
!
 address-family ipv4
  network 3.3.3.3 mask 255.255.255.255
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 activate
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 send-community both
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 next-hop-self
  exit-address-family
!
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 activate
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 send-community both
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 next-hop-self
  exit-address-family
!
 address-family ipv4 vrf JM_CORP
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 remote-as 65000
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 activate
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 send-community both
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 as-override
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  neighbor 100.65.0.2 route-map BGP_POLICY_IN in
  exit-address-family
!
ip community-list standard REGIONAL_LP_100 permit 65000:100
ip community-list standard REGIONAL_LP_200 permit 65000:200
ip community-list standard REGIONAL_LP_300 permit 65000:300
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 10
 match community REGIONAL_LP_100
 set local-preference 333
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 20
 match community REGIONAL_LP_200
 set local-preference 200
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 30
 match community REGIONAL_LP_300
 set local-preference 300
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 40
!
PE#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       3.3.3.3 is directly connected, Loopback0
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.4 [110/21] via 10.0.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/0
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.5 [110/21] via 10.0.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.0.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       10.0.0.3/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
O       10.1.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.0.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/0
O       10.2.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.0.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/0
PE#show ip eigrp topology
```

**REMOTE_CPE:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 6.6.6.6 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description connected to remote_lan_swith
 ip address 10.9.1.11 255.255.255.224
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description connected to remote_pe
 ip address 100.65.1.2 255.255.255.252
!
router eigrp 100
 network 10.9.1.0 0.0.0.31
 network 192.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
 redistribute bgp 65000 metric 100000 100 255 1 1500 route-map BGP_TO_EIGRP
 eigrp router-id 6.6.6.6
!
router bgp 65000
 bgp router-id 6.6.6.6
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 100.65.1.1 remote-as 3549
!
 address-family ipv4
  network 6.6.6.6 mask 255.255.255.255
  redistribute eigrp 100 route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP
  neighbor 100.65.1.1 activate
  neighbor 100.65.1.1 send-community both
  neighbor 100.65.1.1 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  exit-address-family
!
route-map BGP_TO_EIGRP permit 5
 set tag 10
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP deny 5
 match tag 10
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP permit 10
 match tag 100
 set community 65000:100
!
route-map EIGRP_TO_BGP permit 20
 match tag 200
 set community 65000:200
!
REMOTE_CPE#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       1.1.1.1 [20/0] via 100.65.1.1, 1d19h
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       2.2.2.2 [20/0] via 100.65.1.1, 1d19h
     6.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       6.6.6.6 is directly connected, Loopback0
     9.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       9.9.9.9 [20/0] via 100.65.1.1, 1d19h
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 3 masks
D EX    10.0.40.0/30 [170/307200] via 10.9.1.1, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
C       10.9.1.0/27 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       10.9.1.11/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
     50.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    50.50.50.50 [170/409600] via 10.9.1.1, 1d21h, Ethernet0/0
     100.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       100.65.1.0/30 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
L       100.65.1.2/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
B       100.100.100.100/32 [20/0] via 100.65.1.1, 1d22h
REMOTE_CPE#show ip eigrp topology
EIGRP-IPv4 Topology Table for AS(100)/ID(6.6.6.6)
Codes: P - Passive, A - Active, U - Update, Q - Query, R - Reply,
       r - reply Status, s - sia Status
P 10.9.1.0/27, 1 successors, FD is 281600
        via Connected, Ethernet0/0
P 50.50.50.50/32, 1 successors, FD is 409600, tag is 200
        via 10.9.1.1 (409600/128256), Ethernet0/0
P 100.100.100.100/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 10.0.40.0/30, 1 successors, FD is 307200, tag is 200
        via 10.9.1.1 (307200/281600), Ethernet0/0
P 2.2.2.2/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 6.6.6.6/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 1.1.1.1/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
P 9.9.9.9/32, 1 successors, FD is 51200, tag is 10
        via Redistributed (51200/0)
```

**REMOTE_LAN_SWITCH:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 50.50.50.50 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description connected remote_cpe
 no switchport
 ip address 10.9.1.1 255.255.255.224
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description connected to LAN_sw
 no switchport
 ip address 10.0.40.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
!
router eigrp 100
 network 10.9.1.0 0.0.0.31
 network 192.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
 redistribute connected route-map TAG
!
router bgp 600
 bgp router-id 50.50.50.50
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.0.40.1 remote-as 500
!
 address-family ipv4
  redistribute connected
  redistribute eigrp 100 route-map EIGRP-TO-BGP
  neighbor 10.0.40.1 activate
  exit-address-family
!
route-map EIGRP-TO-BGP permit 10
!
route-map BGP-TO-EIGRP permit 10
!
route-map TAG permit 10
set tag 200
!
REMOTE_LAN_SWITCH#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       1.1.1.1 [20/0] via 10.0.40.1, 1d19h
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       2.2.2.2 [20/307200] via 10.0.40.1, 1d19h
     6.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    6.6.6.6 [170/307200] via 10.9.1.11, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
     9.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       9.9.9.9 [20/0] via 10.0.40.1, 1d19h
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 3 masks
C       10.0.40.0/30 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
L       10.0.40.2/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
C       10.9.1.0/27 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
L       10.9.1.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
     50.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       50.50.50.50 is directly connected, Loopback0
     100.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D EX    100.100.100.100 [170/307200] via 10.9.1.11, 1d19h, Ethernet0/0
B       192.168.0.0/24 [20/0] via 10.0.40.1, 1d19h
REMOTE_LAN_SWITCH#show ip eigrp topology
EIGRP-IPv4 Topology Table for AS(100)/ID(50.50.50.50)
Codes: P - Passive, A - Active, U - Update, Q - Query, R - Reply,
       r - reply Status, s - sia Status
P 10.9.1.0/27, 1 successors, FD is 281600
        via Connected, Ethernet0/0
P 50.50.50.50/32, 1 successors, FD is 128256, tag is 200
        via Rconnected (128256/0)
P 100.100.100.100/32, 1 successors, FD is 307200, tag is 10
        via 10.9.1.11 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 10.0.40.0/30, 1 successors, FD is 281600, tag is 200
        via Rconnected (281600/0)
P 2.2.2.2/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 10.9.1.11 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 6.6.6.6/32, 1 successors, FD is 307200, tag is 10
        via 10.9.1.11 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 1.1.1.1/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 10.9.1.11 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
P 9.9.9.9/32, 0 successors, FD is Inaccessible, tag is 10
        via 10.9.1.11 (307200/51200), Ethernet0/0
```

**REMOTE_PE:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255
 ip ospf 100 area 0
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description connected to remote_cpe
 ip vrf forwarding JM_CORP
 ip address 100.65.1.1 255.255.255.252
!
router ospf 100
 network 5.5.5.5 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
!
router bgp 3549
 bgp router-id 5.5.5.5
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 remote-as 3549
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
!
 address-family ipv4
  network 5.5.5.5 mask 255.255.255.255
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 activate
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 send-community both
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 next-hop-self
  exit-address-family
!
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 activate
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 send-community both
  neighbor 4.4.4.4 next-hop-self
  exit-address-family
!
 address-family ipv4 vrf JM_CORP
  redistribute static
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 remote-as 65000
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 activate
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 send-community both
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 as-override
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 soft-reconfiguration inbound
  neighbor 100.65.1.2 route-map BGP_POLICY_IN in
  exit-address-family
!
ip route vrf JM_CORP 100.100.100.100 255.255.255.255 Null0
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 10
 match community REGIONAL_LP_100
 set local-preference 100
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 20
 match community REGIONAL_LP_200
 set local-preference 200
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 30
 match community REGIONAL_LP_300
 set local-preference 300
!
route-map BGP_POLICY_IN permit 40
!
REMOTE_PE#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/21] via 10.1.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet1/1
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.4 [110/21] via 10.1.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet1/1
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       5.5.5.5 is directly connected, Loopback0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
O       10.0.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.1.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet1/1
C       10.1.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet1/1
L       10.1.0.5/32 is directly connected, Ethernet1/1
O       10.2.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.1.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet1/1
REMOTE_PE#show ip eigrp topology
```

**RR:**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.255
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description connected to CORE_P
 ip address 10.2.0.9 255.255.255.0
!
router ospf 100
 network 4.4.4.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
!
router bgp 3549
 bgp router-id 4.4.4.4
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 3549
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 remote-as 3549
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 update-source Loopback0
!
 address-family ipv4
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 activate
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 send-community both
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 route-reflector-client
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 activate
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 send-community both
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 route-reflector-client
  exit-address-family
!
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 activate
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 send-community both
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 route-reflector-client
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 activate
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 send-community both
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 route-reflector-client
  exit-address-family
!
RR#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

     3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       3.3.3.3 [110/21] via 10.2.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/2
     4.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       4.4.4.4 is directly connected, Loopback0
     5.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.5 [110/21] via 10.2.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/2
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
O       10.0.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.2.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/2
O       10.1.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.2.0.4, 1d22h, Ethernet0/2
C       10.2.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
L       10.2.0.9/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/2
RR#show ip eigrp topology
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include the topology and configurations that you reference.

Comment: @RonMaupin, the configuration and topology can be found at the link provided

Comment: You need to move it into your question. This site is meant to serve as an archive, and the content of the link can change, or the whole link could break. You need to edit your question to include the topology and configurations. Please do not use pictures for text, use the preformatted text feature for text, and you can use pictures for things like the topology.

Comment: I think its done now.

Comment: I do not see anything I have requested in your question. All you have is a link. Please, edit your question to include everything I have asked for. See [this question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/24940/8499) for what I mean.

Comment: I edited your question for you. If you want people to help you, you need to provide the necessary information in your question, otherwise people will just ignore the question. I will not do this for you again.

Comment: Thanks @ron. I'll make sure I get it right next time. Cheers

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems:

- You are tagging `10.0.40.0/30` with `100` on LAN_SW, but there is no
  `7.7.7.7/32` anywhere, so you will never tag that route
- You are rewriting the tag for `10.0.40.0/30` with `200` on
  REMOTE_LAN_SWITCH
- The tag `100` on `10.0.40.0/30` goes from LAN_SW to CPE, but you do not run EIGRP between CPE and PE, so `10.0.40.0/30` with the tag `100` gets dropped between those routers, and you seem to want to redistribute from EIGRP to BGP on CPE, but you have BGP problems between CPE and PE, putting the routes from CPE into a VRF that goes nowhere, so `10.0.40.0/30` never goes to PE

You need to take it one router at a time, and make sure that you are advertising the routes you think you should between the two routers on a link.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding ... really very rude of me. Thanks @ronmaupin